# Waiting for a Runnable to complete before running another Runnable

Tags: java, android

I have an Android app with a main tab activity, and several activities within the individual tabs. In my main activity's onCreate(), I have a runnable that creates a list, and in the individual activities, I make use of this list.

In the individual activities's onCreate(), I also have Runnables that operate on the list. However, I need these Runnables to only run when the main tab activity's Runnable completes creating the list, otherwise I'd get a null list. I'm trying to find an elegant way of doing this. Right now, in my main activity's Runnable, I'm setting a global boolean variable isDone, and in my individual activity's Runnable, I'm waiting for isDone to be set via a while loop. This works, but probably isn't the best way of doing so.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Edit:
I'm trying the following code out, but I'm getting runtime errors:

In my MainActivity's Runnable:

```
mainRunnable = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    try {
      generateList();
      synchronized(this) {
      listDone = true;
      notifyAll();
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e("BACKGROUND_PROC", e.getMessage());
    }
  }
};
Thread thread = new Thread(null, mainRunnable, "Background");
thread.start();
```

In my OtherActivity's Runnable:

```
otherRunnable = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    synchronized(MainActivity.mainRunnable) {
      if (!MainActivity.getListDone()) {
        try {
          wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
Thread thread = new Thread(null, otherRunnable, "Background");
thread.start();
```

The mainRunnable seems to run completely, but the otherRunnable seems to cause the app to crash. I get the following error message:

```
01-10 15:41:25.543: E/WindowManager(7074): Activity com.myapp.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40539850 that was originally added here
01-10 15:41:25.543: E/WindowManager(7074): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.myapp.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40539850 that was originally added here
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the `wait` and `notify` methods.

To do this, there needs to be some globally accessible object whose lock isn't used by anything else in the program at this point in time. I'm assuming that the list-creating `Runnable` itself can play this role.

So you could add something like this to the list-creating `Runnable` class:

```
private boolean listsDone = false;

boolean getListsDone() {
    return listsDone;
}
```

And something like this to its `run()` method, immediately after it's done creating the lists:

```
synchronized (this) {
    listsDone = true;
    notifyAll();
}
```

And something like this to the other `Runnable`s' `run()` methods, at the point where they need to wait:

```
synchronized (listCreatingRunnableObject) {
    if (!listCreatingRunnableObject.getListsDone()) {
        try {
            listCreatingRunnableObject.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // handle it somehow
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:** To clarify, both `synchronized` blocks need to be synchronized over the same object, and you have to call `wait()` and `notifyAll()` on that object. If the object is the `Runnable`, then it can be implicit for the first one (as in the above code), but if it's the activity, you need to explicitly use the activity object in both cases.

Comment: Thanks. What exactly is listCreatingRunnableObject? Is it the activity class or the Runnable?

Comment: @user1118764 I'm assuming it's the Runnable, but it can be any globally accessible object.

Comment: I get the following error when I try to use your code in the other Runnable's run() method:
01-10 15:24:27.003: W/dalvikvm(5857): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
01-10 15:24:27.023: E/AndroidRuntime(5857): FATAL EXCEPTION: Background
01-10 15:24:27.023: E/AndroidRuntime(5857): java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()

Comment: @user1118764 D'oh! I forgot that you have to call `wait()` on the object that you're using for synchronization. See the update to my answer.

Comment: @user1118764 I'm confused. You said there's only one list, so if it's already been created, then there's nothing to wait for and you can immediately do whatever comes next (which is why the `if` clause is there, aside from deadlock prevention). That's what you want, right?

Comment: Thanks, that works!

Previously I put the stuff I had to do within the try segment. I took it out and now they get executed correctly.

Comment: @user1118764 FYI, if this answer gave you what you were looking for, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 13):

You can use a `Queue` like this:

```
public class RunQueue implemements Runnable
{
  private List<Runnable> list = new ArrayList<Runnable>();

  public void queue(Runnable task)
  {
    list.add(task);
  }

  public void run()
  {
    while(list.size() > 0)
    {
      Runnable task = list.get(0);

      list.remove(0);
      task.run();
    } 
  }
}
```

This allows you to use one thread rather than multiple threads. And you can maintain all your existing "Runnable" objects while simultaneously cleaning up any code they have for waits and joins.

Comment: I was trying to do the same thing, and I thought of doing this but didn't think it would work like I'd wanted. Seeing this answer I tried it out and it works perfectly. By far the simplest way to achieve this. Cheers!

Comment: Is there a way to get this run in a loop? I want one thread to run over and over again (infinitely), but they can't stack up. IT must run one at a time. @64BitBob

Comment: @Riptyde4 - Just replace the while/remove with a while(true) with a for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {list.get(i).run();}. If you want it to wait between loops, add a Thread.sleep() at the beginning or end of the while(true) block.

Comment: Shouldn't is be task.run() ?

Comment: @Mukul - Holy cow! I can't believe that bug has gone unnoticed for so long. I've updated the post to fix the bug. Good catch!

Comment: `Runnable task = list.get(0);` seems to give an error regarding incompatible types. The result from `list.get()` needs to be casted to a `Runnable` first. Other than that, this seems to work quite nicely!

Answer (score 9):

Set up a CountDownLatch with a value of 1 in the main thread, then have the dependent threads wait on it. When the main thread is done, you Count Down the latch to 0 and the waiters will start right up.

Comment: Thank you, CountDownLatch saved my day.

Answer (score 3):

An active wait using a `while` loop is not a good idea at all. The simplest thing would be for the first Runnable to just fire up the rest of them as its last step. If that can't be made to work for some reason, take a look at posting a message to a Handler.

Comment: Thanks. I did the first approach and it worked, but it didn't seem like a good idea either. I'm trying to do it via the wait/notify approach now.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are using `Runnable`s and not `Thread`s? If you use `Thread`s, you can use the various thread communication primitives which exist for this exact reason (`wait()` and `join()` in particular).

Comment: No reason, other than the fact that the example code I used declared a Runnable myRunnable, and then ran it with calls to:
Thread thread = new Thread(null, myRunnable, "background");
thread.start
Not sure if this is a Runnable or a thread?

Comment: @user1118764 You might still be able to directly access the Thread objects that way. However, if you use `wait()` (as I suggest in my answer), you don't need to, and you only want to use `join()` if you want to wait for the thread in question to finish executing entirely, rather than just complete some particular task.

Comment: If you use new Thread(), then you are dealing with a Thread. So you can go ahead and use the communication mechanism I mentioned (and described in detail by Taymon in this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8799584/570930 )

Answer (score 0):

I have created a helper method that contains all the boilerplate code for posting a runnable and waiting until it finishes running.

The logic is similar to what @Taymon describes, but the implementation is more general.

Check it out:
https://gist.github.com/Petrakeas/ce745536d8cbae0f0761

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can refer to Looper in Android.  Simply, a thead keep running task from queue in a `while` loop.