# How to handling asynchronous in Service to execute task synchronous in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, react-native, react-native-native-module

> My Question is not duplicated as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799373/waiting-for-a-runnable-to-complete-before-running-another-runnable)!
>   my case is about AsyncTask not just about Runnable, and even so, I've 2 AsyncTask inside runnable that needed to handling!

I'm new in Android, I've an app created by [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/). but the problem is I want to upload any data (image [jpg] & video [mp4]) that stored in `sqlite` to server through rest-API and handling the task in android ([Native Module](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html))

Workflow :

- My service need to keep running on background to check any data stored on `sqlite`

  1. the service will compressing size of mp4 extention before sending (using [FFMPeg](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java))
  2. the service will delete the real video
  3. the service will send the data into server (I add 1 column called `flag` to check if the video already compressed)

Problem :

I've create `compressTask` and `sending` function inside service, but the `compressTask` and `sending` using `extends AsyncTask` that mean if the `compressTask` already execute, `sending` function will execute too when `compressTask` not yet finished,

Example :
I've 2 row of video in sqlite, the service will execute `compressTask` and already have 1 video compressed, but `sending` will executed before 2nd video already compressed

Expected Result :
I want to handle sending to wait 2 video already compressed, How can I do that?

My code :

```
public class myService extends Service {
    public Runnable mRunnable = null;
    private boolean mRunning = false;
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    String newPathOutputVideo = null;
    int idProcessVideo = 0;
    String log = null;
    @Inject
    FFmpeg ffmpeg;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public myService getServerInstance() {
            return myService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        loadFFmpeg();
        Log.d("Service"," onstart kepanggil ga?");
        mRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /* ---New Code--- */
                Log.d("Service","SERVICE RUN");
                compressTask c = new compressTask();
                c.execute();

                sending a = new sending();
                a.execute();
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 10 * 1000);
            }
        };
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 10 * 1000);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Waiting for a Runnable to complete before running another Runnable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799373/waiting-for-a-runnable-to-complete-before-running-another-runnable)

Comment: `sending function will execute too when compressTask not yet finished,`. No. That does not happen. The doInBackground()s of AsyncTasks are executed sequentially.

Comment: You could start the send asynctask in the onPostExecute of the compress task.

Comment: Just start your tasks in the sequence you want them to be executed.

Comment: plus1 for `send asynctask in the onPostExecute of the compress task` idea, never try this,